# How to generate a URL Link on the desktop in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut-file

I am looking for the option to create a URL link with Inno Setup on the desktop.

I need to call my web application with some parameters. Till now I was only able to create a shortcut to my application folder an my program, but how to create a URL link?

I think it must be solved in the `Icons` section?

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyAPP"; Filename: "{app}\MYPROG.EXE"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{group}\App Logs"; Filename:"{commonappdata}\Foo\App\logfiles"; \
    WorkingDir: "{commonappdata}\Foo\App\logfiles" 
Name: "{group}\Uninstall"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the [`Filename` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=Filename) to the URL:

> **Filename**  (Required)
> ...
> In addition to file and folder names, **URLs (web site addresses) may also be specified**. When a URL is specified, Setup will create an "Internet Shortcut" (.url) file, and ignore the `Parameters`, `WorkingDir`, `HotKey`, and `Comment` parameters.

Example:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autodesktop}\Web"; Filename: "https://www.example.com/"
```

Answer (score -1):

Internet shortcuts must be specified in INI section

```
[INI]
FileName={commondesktop}\MyShortcutName.url,Section:InternetShortcut;Key:URL;String: Http://MyShortcutName.com
```

Comment: Shortcuts (while different type) can be created using `INI` section indeed, but it's not true that they *"must"*. The `Icons` solution is my answer works too.

Comment: And your syntax is wrong. There should be colon and semicolon, not equal sign and comma.